# How to prove the optimal solution exists for a nonlinear optimal control problem?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, optimal-control, nonlinear-analysis

I am doing a nonlinear optimal control design project, typically a practical engineering problem.

It is easy to solve that with direct method. However, I am wondering is there any way to prove that the optimal solution exists ? Further, since the direct method is employed, is there anyway to prove that the numerical solution will converge to that optimal solution?

Could anyone offer me some reference paper about that ?

thanks

Jie

Comment: An answer to this question may depend on the nature of the nonlinearity.  Theorems for certain classes of nonlinearities exist.  So what type of nonlinearity are you working with?

Comment: @EricTowers  what is "type of nonlinearity"?

Comment: Nonexhaustive lists of examples of named types for [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nonlinear_ordinary_differential_equations)s and [PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nonlinear_partial_differential_equations)s.  If it is a named type, then you have greater chance finding, for example, [The Time Optimal Control of the Boussinesq Equations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233481082_The_Time_Optimal_Control_of_the_Boussinesq_Equations).

Comment: @EricTowers Actually, the dynamics is characterized by ODEs with state-space form. The index performance is time-energy form.     I attached a similar paper.  The dynamic equations can be found in the following paper. Eric, Could you help me to identify that ? thanks. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0967066115300642?casa_token=INLW0yRKJxIAAAAA:ul2sO-Pxdd5SBspem8e6ik2rMO3IiYk66pT_Dem-IBkazXHwg5TOKK4b4qFX4nfSwkRzlm37t3HL.